# add file to collections framework from file

Tags: java

I am not trying to duplicate threads here.
My problem is i am piping in a file using msdos called amazon.txt
the file has 637 words in it..
I want a count of unique words.. and not a count of "a", "the" , "this"
which i havent counted for yet in the code..

when i add to a tree set it only has 8 words..
There should be atlest 300 unique words..

count of total file = 637
count2 of treeset = 8

I thought treeset handles duplicates? what am i doing wrong?
The file does contain some ints an $

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class practice1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner     sc = new Scanner(System.in);    
        String      word;
        //String grab;
        int count = 0;
        int count2 =0;
        int count3 =0;
        int count4 =0;
        int number;
        //ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
        TreeSet<String> a = new TreeSet<String>();

        while (sc.hasNext()) 
        {
            word = sc.next();
            count++;           // 637 words
            a.add(word);
            if (word.equals("---"))
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        Iterator<String> it = a.iterator();

        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            string grab = it.next(); 
            count2++;                   // 8 words

            if (grab.equals("---"))
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("count2");
        System.out.println(count2);
        System.out.println("count");
        System.out.println(count);          
        System.out.println("\nbye...");
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome at SO! A starter hint: don't mix tabs and spaces in your editor. It would mess code indenting. In most decent editors you can configure to insert 4 spaces for each tab.

Comment: please please never use tabs again - you need to fix your editor so that it converts tabs to spaces and you will find that the code is readable no matter what editor you use.

Comment: @TofuBeer: copypaste in Eclipse, hit `Ctrl+Shift+F`, copypaste back ;)

Comment: am I blind or are you not actually adding anything to the TreeSet in this code?

Comment: I was commenting out some code and i accidently took out the add part. i added it back in..

Comment: @BalusC can do that in netbeans - I just didn't know it was as bad as it was :-)  I usually use Jalopy (great product, closest one to making sure code looks the way I want it).

Answer (score 2):

Your method for counting the number of entries in the TreeSet is to iterate over the Set and stop counting when you first see the string `"---"`.

This isn't correct. You are probably assuming that the order of entries returned by `TreeSet.iterator()` is the same order as  which they were inserted in. That [isn't the case](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html):

> The elements are ordered using their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at set creation time, depending on which constructor is used.

"Natural ordering" here means the results of `String.compareTo(String)` (since String implements `Comparable<String>`), which tests for lexicographical order. In other words, a the iterator of a `TreeSet<String>` returns the items in alphabetical order.

If you want to know the size of your Set, just use `size()`.

Comment: good catch... I'd just not add the --- and it should probably work (I didn't add it for my testing... oops).  Just move the if (word.equals("---")) part above the add.

Comment: No, you should change the way in which you are counting the size of the TreeSet. You can't just stop when you find a token, because the order of iteration is not the same as the order of insertion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anywhere where you are adding the word into the TreeSet 'a'.

If I'm just missing that (and I might be) I'd bet the problem is that a TreeSet is not guaranteed to iterate in the order of insertion. That is, you add "---" last but there's no reason it won't come out of the iterator 8th and terminate your program.

So I'd say get rid of the check where you see if the iterator returns "---" and see where that gets you.

---

Had time to verify, change:

```
    if (grab.equals("---"))
    {
        break;
    }
```

to:

```
    if (grab.equals("---"))
    {
        //break;
    }
```

and it works as expected.

Good luck!

Comment: I was commenting out some code and i accidently took out the add part. i added it back in..

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to iterate a 2nd time, just replace 2nd loop with

```
System.out.println("Treeset.size():" + a.size() );
```

and do not add "---" to treeset in the first loop (assuming this is some kind of end of file marker)

```
if (word.equals("---"))
{
    break;
}
a.add(word);
```